# Methods for Class coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm very new in coffeescript and also with objects in javascript.
I have this piece of code in coffeescript:

```
class Animal
constructor: (name) ->
    @name = name
    @upperName: ->
        @name.toUpperCase()
    @greetings ->
        console.log 'Hello %s', @name

this.type = 'Animal'
```

That is "compiled" into this javascript:

```
var Animal
Animal = (function() {
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
  ({
    this.upperName: function() {
      return this.name.toUpperCase();
    }
  });
  this.greetings(function() {
    return console.log('Hello %s', this.name);
  });
}
Animal.type = 'Animal';
return Animal;
})();
```

What's the difference between the methods *greetings* and *upperName*???
What the "*:*" do in a class?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Symbol summary (left=CS, right=JS)

Within `class Animal`:

```
identifier: value        Animal.prototype.identifier = value
@identifier: value       Animal.identifier           = value
@identifier= value       Animal.identifier           = value
identifier = value       identifier                  = value  (private var)
```

Elsewhere (ordered by same compiled result)

```
Animal::identifier = value  Animal.prototype.identifier = value
Animal.identifier  = value  Animal.identifier           = value
identifier = value          identifier                  = value
// New:
@identifier = value         this.identifier             = value
identifier: value           { identifier: value}                 (object literal)
@identifier: value          ---INVALID---
```

---

In CoffeeScript, @ compiles to `this`.

In the context of a `class` construct, the method definition is affected by use of `@` (this). Here's a simple example:

```
class ClassObject
    instanceMethod: ->
        # This method will be defined on the prototype (available to instance)

    @classMethod: ->
        # This method is defined on the class object itself, not on the instance

    this.classMethod2 = -> # See previous and below
    privateVar = "private"
```

Although the syntax slightly differs, the latest two have the same compiled result.

#### "What does `:` mean inside a class block?"

It is used to define properties. When `=` (is equal sign) is used instead, a "private" variable will be defined.

#### "What does `:` mean inside the (constructor) method?

Outside the level of a class (eg top-level code, inside a function, constructor, etc.), `:` does not have the "special class" meaning. `:` is the separator between key-name pairs within an object literal.
Your given code, `@upperName: -> ...` is invalid, and does not compile in the latest CoffeeScript version. `upperName: -> ...` is valid though, and will compile to an object literal with property `upperName` and a function as a value.

---

Have a look at the [compiled CoffeeScript code](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20ClassObject%0A%20%20%20%20instanceMethod:%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20This%20method%20will%20be%20defined%20on%20the%20prototype%20%28available%20to%20instance%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20@classMethod:%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20This%20method%20is%20defined%20on%20the%20class%20object%20itself,%20not%20on%20the%20instance%0A%0A%20%20%20%20this.classMethod2%20=%20-%3E%20#%20See%20previous%20and%20below%0A%20%20%20%20privateVar%20=%20%22private%22):

```
var ClassObject;

ClassObject = (function() {
  var privateVar;

  function ClassObject() {}

  ClassObject.prototype.instanceMethod = function() {};

  ClassObject.classMethod = function() {};

  ClassObject.classMethod2 = function() {};

  privateVar = "private";

  return ClassObject;

})();
```

Comment: Ok...another thing about the privateVar....it is one for each instance of ClassObject or it is a private static variable??

Comment: It is a "static private variable" (you can also see that in the compiled result).

Answer (score 0):

The code with the indentation you wrote does not compile. Here is what I think you mean:

```
class Animal
  constructor: (name) ->
    @name = name

  upperName: ->
    @name.toUpperCase()

  greetings: ->
    console.log "Hello #{@name}"
```

If you compile that, the output should make a lot more sense. If we run this with the following code:

```
a = new Animal 'panda'
console.log a.name
console.log a.upperName()
a.greetings()
```

we get the expected output:

```
panda
PANDA
Hello panda
```

Class definitions are like normal object definitions - they are a set of properties and values. In this case we defined an animal to be a set of 3 properties which are all functions (the constructor, upperName, and greetings).